# how to do grouping of analytics data?

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, grouping, analytics

I am working on a Unity3D augmented reality app (iOS and Android) where I want to send AR campaign data to Google Analytics.

**Example of what I exactly want to do**

Information about AR campaigns available,
Category (can be anything...automobile, entertainment or travel), campaign name (each campaign is related to only one of the categories), user gender and age (available from login details).

**I want the grouping of data on Google Analytics by,**

1. category - data of all the campaigns grouped by each category
2. gender in a given category - data of how many males / females scanned a particular campaign, category wise
3. age in a given category - data of user's age who scanned a particular campaign, category wise
4. gender regardless of the category - data of how many males / females scanned a particular campaign irrespective of category
5. age regardless of the category - data of user's age who scanned a particular campaign irrespective of category

So as to generate and export reports for each of the above mentioned group.

I sent a couple of screens and events to GA but not sure how to group data as per my requirements and generate reports. I couldn't find any documentation of tutorial that describes a similar use-case. I am using the [latest plugin](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity/raw/master/googleanalyticsv3.unitypackage) from [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v3/devguide).

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is better suited for the Webmasters forum, as the question is not related to coding.

Comment: thanks! did that. I am not sure if I shall delete this question from here...or wait if someone answers